# How to format NSPredicate for PHFetchOptions in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, photokit, phasset

I cannot figure out the proper format necessary to define a `predicate` for an instance of `PHFetchOptions`. I've tried so many combinations but they either do not compile or no assets are returned.

The goal is to get only the photos (no videos) in a given collection:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %i", "PHAssetMediaType.Image")
assetsFetchResults = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(assetCollection, options: options)
```

I've tried all combinations of `==`, `%d`, `%@`, `PHAssetMediaTypeImage`, `"PHAssetMediaTypeImage"`, `PHAssetMediaType.Image`, etc.

Comment: You can also use the function `PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(_ mediaType: PHAssetMediaType, options options: PHFetchOptions!)`, which might be a more direct way of getting photos only.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue)
```

Of course I figure it out, right after posting. ;)